# How to Drag from scrollView to superview then back to scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to animate a drag from a ScrollView containing numerous auto-generated buttons, onto the main view.

The following code does what I need (I can probably still clean it up a bit), 
EXCEPT, after the the drag completes, I want it to snap back to its original location on the scroll bar.

The code below will replace the button in the same location, but basically on top of the entire view, rather than on the scroll bar.

Any suggestions of a simple way to return it to the subview when it returns?

Thank you for any help!
John

```
    @IBAction func handleScrollPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            scrollView.superview?.addSubview(recognizer.view!)
            let currentPoint = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x, y:recognizer.view!.center.y)
            let newPoint = scrollView.convert(currentPoint, to: self.view)
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            if let view = recognizer.view {
                view.center = CGPoint(x:newPoint.x + translation.x,
                                      y:newPoint.y + translation.y)
            }
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), in: self.view)
            firstLocation = CGPoint(x:scrollView.center.x, y:scrollView.center.y)

        } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                       animations: {recognizer.view!.center = firstLocation},
                       completion: nil)

        } else {
            scrollView.superview?.addSubview(recognizer.view!)
            let currentPoint = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view!.center.x, y:recognizer.view!.center.y)
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            if let view = recognizer.view {
                view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            }
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: I figure out the answer to my own question, but I'm posting here in case anyone else has the same dilemma.

Comment: I figured out the answer to my own question, but I'm posting here in case anyone else has the same dilemma. I added a line in the `.began` section to convert the original point to the scrollView coordinates: `let origPoint = self.view.convert(newPoint, to: self.scrollView`. Then in the `.ended` section, I just set the current view to the 'firstLocation' and added it back to the scrollView with addSubview: `scrollView.addSubview(newView)`